# I want to write a python code using tkinter to get textbox value and output it. But Its not working properly

Tags: python, tkinter

.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

class sign:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gui=Tk()
        self.gui.geometry("800x450")
        self.gui.title("Quiz")
        self.signup_form()
   
    def signup_form(self):
        global username
        global password
        self.username = StringVar()
        self.password = StringVar()
        Label(self.gui, text="").pack()
        Label(self.gui, text="Username :", fg="black", font=('arial', 12, 'bold')).pack()
        Entry(self.gui, textvariable=self.username).pack()
        Label(self.gui, text="").pack()
        Label(self.gui, text="Password :", fg="black", font=('arial', 12, 'bold')).pack()
        Entry(self.gui, textvariable=self.password, show="*").pack()
        Label(self.gui, text="").pack()
        Button(self.gui, text="sign up", bg="white", fg='blue', relief="solid", font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),command=self.msg).pack()
        Label(self.gui, text="")
        
        
    def msg(self):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Msg",self.username)
    

signup=sign()
```

Comment: "But Its not working properly" is *not* a very useful bug report. Good questions have (1) the expected behaviour, (2) the actual behaviour, and (3) shortest code sample that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Please copy your entire code properly.

Comment: You don't seem to be using the two `globals` here - maybe remove them. Also, what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

class sign:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gui=Tk()
        self.gui.geometry("800x450")
        self.gui.title("Quiz")
        self.signup_form()
        self.gui.mainloop()
   
    def signup_form(self):
        global username
        global password
        self.username = StringVar()
        self.password = StringVar()
        Label(self.gui, text="").pack()
        Label(self.gui, text="Username :", fg="black", font=('arial', 12, 'bold')).pack()
        Entry(self.gui, textvariable=self.username).pack()
        Label(self.gui, text="").pack()
        Label(self.gui, text="Password :", fg="black", font=('arial', 12, 'bold')).pack()
        Entry(self.gui, textvariable=self.password, show="*").pack()
        Label(self.gui, text="").pack()
        Button(self.gui, text="sign up", bg="white", fg='blue', relief="solid", font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),command=self.msg).pack()
        Label(self.gui, text="")
        
        
    def msg(self):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Msg",self.username.get())
    

signup=sign()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer your question and improve your code a bit (with explanation)

##### sections:

- problem solving
- classes and tkinter

I assume you want the code to run like this:

1. start gui.
2. input username and password.
3. show username in messagebox.
4. run program

##### problem solving

I think you mean with "not working properly" that it outputs "PY_VAR0". What happens here is that you're not actually extracting the input of the textbox, but the name that python gives it to identify it. To solve this just use the `get()` function.

```py
def msg(self):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Msg",self.username.get())
```

##### classes and tkinter

In tkinter there's something called `mainloop()`. that makes sure that the gui gets displayed and the program responds to the users input. If you use classes,  you should add a parameter `master` in the `__init__()` function. then below your class you can specify your master. I will call him `root` because it's the commonly used name for a master.

```py
class sign:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.gui=master
        self.gui.geometry("800x450")
        self.gui.title("Quiz")


root = Tk()
signup = sign(root)
root.mainloop()
```

> Tip: if you want to use multiple windows, use [toplevels](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_toplevel.htm).

This is the complete code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

class sign:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.gui=master
        self.gui.geometry("800x450")
        self.gui.title("Quiz")
        self.signup_form()
   
    def signup_form(self):
        self.username = StringVar()
        self.password = StringVar()
        Label(self.gui, text="").pack()
        Label(self.gui, text="Username :", fg="black", font=('arial', 12, 'bold')).pack()
        Entry(self.gui, textvariable=self.username).pack()
        Label(self.gui, text="").pack()
        Label(self.gui, text="Password :", fg="black", font=('arial', 12, 'bold')).pack()
        Entry(self.gui, textvariable=self.password, show="*").pack()
        Label(self.gui, text="").pack()
        Button(self.gui, text="sign up", bg="white", fg='blue', relief="solid", font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),command=self.msg).pack()
        Label(self.gui, text="")
        
    def msg(self):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Msg",self.username.get())
        username = self.username.get()
        password = self.password.get()


username = ""
password = ""
root = Tk()
signup = sign(root)
root.mainloop()
```

> Tip: take a look at [this course](https://python-course.eu/python-tutorial/global-local-variables-namespaces.php) about the difference between global and local variables

Comment: My problem is solved.Thank  you so much for your answers.